# Complex limit using $\delta$-$\epsilon$

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

I'm just starting my complex limits and this was the limit I needed to prove $\lim_\limits{z\to z_0}\Re(z)=\Re(z_0)$ proceeding with the standard process $|\Re(z)-\Re(z_0)|<\epsilon$ and $|z-z_0|<\delta$ Using the fact that $\Re(z)=\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}$ we get $\left|\frac{z+\bar{z}}{2}-\frac{z_0+\bar{z_0}}{2}\right|\implies\left|\frac{z-z_0+\overline{z-z_0}}{2}\right|<\epsilon$ at this point I did not know what to do, I remembered in previous $\delta-\epsilon$ proofs I put $\epsilon$ in terms of $\delta$. That doesn't make sense in this case because we get $\left|\frac{\delta+\bar{\delta}}{2}\right|<\epsilon$ which means $\left|\Re(\delta)\right|<\epsilon$. How do I proceed?

Comment: Triangular inequality ?

Comment: Do you know that Re is real-linear and hence continuous?

Comment: An alternative way could be to note that $|z| \geq \sqrt{(\Re(z))^2} = |\Re(z)|$ and apply $z \mapsto z - z_0$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try to show that $|\Re(z)-\Re(z_0)|\leq |z-z_0|$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\R}{\operatorname{Re}}\newcommand{\I}{\operatorname{Im}}$
\begin{align}
\left|\R (z) - \R(z_0)\right| & = \sqrt{(\R(z) - \R(z_0))^2} \\[10pt]
& \le \sqrt{(\R(z) - \R(z_0))^2 + (\I(z) - \I(z_0))^2} = |z-z_0|.
\end{align}